# Is it safe to view virus content on linux?

Tags: linux, virus

My email virus software quarantined several virus files. Is it safe to view them with 'cat' or other similar commands? Also can I safely open them with editors like nano?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use cat, use `strings`, `xxd`, `hexdump` etc. If you really want to know what is going on use a disassembler.

Comment: I haven't thought about this, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat`ing any binary files can screw up your terminal, but you can still return it back to normal by running `reset` command (or just closing it and starting new one)

Otherwise it should be safe.

Probably, there is a way to create some virus that targets vulnerability in e.g. `nano`'s syntax highlighting module, but I haven't heard of such things.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can safely view the virus with those tools, though I'm not sure why you would want to do it. There may be a virus to specifically target a leak in nano or cat or vim or whichever, but the odds of that are so small I'd almost not mention it.